# json.net , Convert object to json with xml data in property

Tags: json.net

I am trying to find a way to serialize an object to json using json.net. The object i am trying to serialize has a XElement property, and i would like to keep it as is so.

is there a way to do that in json.net ? or what the mechanism to transfer xml data in json object?

Comment: To transport XML as JSON: 1) Convert it to JSON (but not done with an automatic converter and using some "possibly lossy" rules), or 2) Shove the XML in a string. In the case of #2 Json.NET will *not* touch the contents. Case #1 might be automatically possible by registering the appropriate converters.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that like this

```
 //convert XML node contained in string xml into a JSON string   
 XmlDocument var = new XmlDocument();
 var.LoadXml(xml);
 string jsonsting = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(var);
```

[see this link for more help](http://ajaxian.com/archives/jsonnet-11-converting-between-xml-and-json)